# MySQL MHA binlog setting check failed

Tags: mysql

i try to config MHA 0.56 for mysql 5.7, everything is done. when i run masterha_check_repl, i get the following message:
`executing command: save_binary_logs --command=test --start_pos=4 --binlog_dir=/data/mysql --output_file=/data/mysql`

`Failed to save binary log: Set --start_file=<starting_binlog_filename> or --binlog_prefix=<binlog_file_prefix>`

`Binlog setting check failed!`

I modified MasterMonitor.pm added
`--binlog_prefix=mysql-bin`
into the command , but it doesn't work, still gave me above error message.

I have no idea on how to deal with it..

Comment: Re "*still gave me above error message.*", Both messages are still the same? Then you didn't properly add `--binlog_prefix=mysql-bin` as you claim.

Comment: but in order to check whether it has been modified, I also change ```--start_pos=4``` to ```--start_pos=5```, finally the error message changed to ```--start_pos=5```, ```but --binlog_prefix=mysql-bin``` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `binlog_prefix` in `my.cnf` rather than via command line.

Comment: the my.cnf include ```log-bin = mysql-bin```. and i also added ```binlog_prefix``` or  ```binlog-prefix``` in ```my.cnf```,mysql throw error, unknow variable   ```binlog_prefix``` or  ```binlog-prefix```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake when I copied other's app1.cnf explanation into my app1.cnf.
The #comment after parameters in the same line should be removed.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question. After you do that, you can delete this answer.